# how to upload data into oracle from csv file where client and server are on different physical systems using java

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, csv

I want to upload data from csv file on client to oracle database on server which is physically on different machine using java. I searched online for solutions but all solutions are working only for the case where both client and server are on same machine.

Please help

```
   String temp = ((System.getenv("USERPROFILE"))+("\\Documents\\"));
        String path = "";

        path = temp.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        path = path + "upload.csv";
        //System.out.println(path);
        Connection connection = MyConnection.getConnection();

            String loadQuery = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + path + "' INTO TABLE documents FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','" + " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ( Customer, address1 )";
            //System.out.println(loadQuery);
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(loadQuery);
```

This path works if the server and client are on same machine, how to modify this when server and client are on different machine ?

Comment: Look at submitting a form of type `enctype="multipart/form-data"` with an `<input type="file">` element.

Comment: I have looked those but only solution i get is of uploading file on server, i want to upload the csv content into database and not file on server.

Comment: after you upload the file to the server then you should parse out the data and store it in the database...

Comment: but this will work once, what if second time someone is uploading and the file name is same?

Comment: This is a different problem. You have to choose what to do in this case: replace file? change the name with a unique name? throw an error? appending the new file to the original one? But nothing to do with what you asked

Comment: It doesn't matter if they upload a file with the same name you are taking the data from the file and storing it in the database then getting rid of the file correct? If all you are after is the data the filename shouldn't matter you can do it as many times as u want.  If you are storing the .csv file in the database as a blob then that is a little different...

Comment: When you upload the file to the server save it as a tempfile with a unique name (maybe add timestamp) then upload to database after done delete the file...

Comment: is there a way to delete that file automatically after reading it ?

Comment: @Prathik in java you can `createTempFile()` which will automatically give the file a unique name and store it in the temp folder on the server then if you want to explicitly delete it you can do `file.Delete()`

Comment: @Prathik no problem man...you might have to do a lot of googling but you should be able to get there...I did something similar where i was uploading a .docx file using a form to submit the file then in my servlet I save the file to the database as a blob.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you have

- A server with oracle
- A server with java
- A file csv on the server with java

And you need to save the data from csv to oracle. Correct?
If so this is a standard java application with I/O to read the file and JDBC access to a remote database.

Basically here are the steps:

```
1) Open the csv
2) Open a database connection
3) Read a row from csv and convert it to an object (if using JPA) 
4) Save the object
5) Go to the next row until finish
6) Commit and close all resources
```

To access a remote database simply substitute 127.0.0.1 (or localhost) from the url connection with the ip of the remote database.

Comment: well this works if server and client are on same machine, what i have is

a server with java and oracle
a client with csv file to be uploaded on oracle

server and client on different physical machines.

Comment: No this work also if client and server are on different machines. If not the problem is not on the java code, but on the permissions on database. For example default installation of MySql has permission to access to it only from localhost.

Comment: what problem i am facing is ia m not able to pass the content of the file from client to server.

Comment: If you know how to save data locally you can do the same remotely. The only differences are: the connection url and the permissions in the database  or problems due to the network (for example a firewall that blocks requests on a particular port)

Comment: You have to show what there is behind to this line of code "MyConnection.getConnection();"

Comment: its getting the connection to the oracle server, thats all

Comment: Yes I know! Is here that you define the connection url. So it is here that you say where is your oracle (locally or in a remote machine). Change your code here or if it uses an external datasource or connection pool or configuration file change it.